# How do I drop all repeated rows based on group after it changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I drop all rows after there is a change in a value in 1 column by group?

I have a data that looks like:

```
    ID  Date       CD
0   1   1/1/2015    A
1   1   1/2/2015    A
2   1   1/3/2015    A
3   1   1/4/2015    A
4   1   1/5/2015    B
5   1   1/6/2015    B
6   1   1/7/2015    A
7   1   1/8/2015    A
8   1   1/9/2016    C
9   2   1/2/2015    A
10  2   1/3/2015    A
11  2   1/4/2015    A
12  2   1/5/2015    A
13  2   1/6/2015    A
14  2   1/7/2015    A
```

I need to drop last 3 rows for ID 1 because it goes back to CD A after it has been changed. Result

I am looking for is :

[image]

Since I am not dropping all duplicates, I couldn't use Duplicates. I am neither keeping all "A" to use loc function.

I tried using groupby and cumcount. Any help would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets create a boolean mask to identify the occurrence of the first row where the value in CD column goes back after it has been changed, then group this mask by ID and use cummax to flag all the rows after such occurrence

```
m = df.duplicated(['ID', 'CD']) & (df['CD'] != df['CD'].shift())
df[~m.groupby(df['ID']).cummax()]
```

---

```
    ID      Date CD
0    1  1/1/2015  A
1    1  1/2/2015  A
2    1  1/3/2015  A
3    1  1/4/2015  A
4    1  1/5/2015  B
5    1  1/6/2015  B
9    2  1/2/2015  A
10   2  1/3/2015  A
11   2  1/4/2015  A
12   2  1/5/2015  A
13   2  1/6/2015  A
14   2  1/7/2015  A
```